# typo3 4.5 convert .zip to .t3x extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-4.5

I am a new player in Typo3 and I have an issue with backward compatibility.

I was developing my personal extension using typo3 version 6.1 platform, and pack it into .zip file. This is possible since Typo3 version 6.1 can accept both .zip and .t3x files when it comes to uploading extensions using Extension Manager. There are no methods to download my extension into .t3x format.

The thing is, now I am working on different site using Typo3 version 4.5, and I would love to use my extension again. Since there are no method whatsoever in Extension Manager to upload .zip extensions, the only option for me is then to convert .zip to .t3x format.

Is there any possible ways for me to do this? Or am I missing some documentations about different work around?

Comment: Unrelated, but if anyone is looking for a tool the other way round (to convert an old t3x extension to a readable zip), try https://tools.bartlweb.net/t3xtozip/ (of course, your code will be visible to 3rd party)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. you don't need to compress your ext into any archive/ext file, just copy whole folder with your extension from `typo3conf/ext/` to identical location in other TYPO3 page and it will behave like it was imported via Extension Manager (don't forget to install it a the end)
2. I really doubt if your ext written for TYPO3 ver. 6.x will work in
   4.x at all...

Comment: Awww snap! I used the MVC extbase mechanism on typo3 6.x (using controllers, models, views with folder structure etc). So I suppose i cannot use it anymore within 4.x?

Comment: The situation isn't hopless: it should be quite easy for you to backport your extbase ext from 6.x to 4.x. Of course you will need to refactor the code as there are differences in syntax, anyway main programming concept of the Extbase remains almost the same. Just use good IDE (ie. PhpStorm) to make whole project smoother.

Comment: If you did not use namespaces in your 6.1 extension, it could pretty much work in 4.5. If you did use namespaces you have to refactor because 4.5 dont know namespaces. Also 4.5 extbase cant interpret @inject annotations.

Comment: AFAIK there is also the possibility to define a mapping file from non-namespaced classes to namespaced classes, so you can keep the use of namespaces while being able to run the ext in older TYPO3 versions. This would increase the PHP version requirement for your 4.5-installation to 5.3 though.